# How to remove unused space in an array

Tags: c

```
#define n 10
int a[n];
```

I wanted to declare an array globally and modify the size in other function

```
int main(){ 
  int b;
  printf("Enter the number of elements\n");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  #undef n
  #define n b
  for(int i = 0;i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  display();
}
```

I modified the size in the main function

```
void display()
{
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

when i enter a size like 5 and enter the elements 1 2 3 4 5
the output shows 5 elements followed by 5 zeroes 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 
how to remove the zeroes?

Comment: C arrays are not resizable. Use dynamic allocation (aka malloc/calloc/realloc).

Comment: You could declare a new variable, say `size`, that keeps track of the number of elements in the array, and when you diplay it, instead of looping from `0` to `n`, loop from `0` to `size`.

Comment: You have some serious confusion about how `#define` works... The preprocessor works just by brutal text substitution, so it's not like changing a `#define` can magically affect a section of text that has already been processed.

Comment: Though this is marked duplicate I am afraid there are few things not to follow from that answer - casting of `malloc` is unnecessary. The `realloc` usage is wrong and it is not a complete example.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Once you declare an array you can't change it's size. As an alternative you can emulate this behavior perfectly using a pointer and then allocating dynamically memory and assigning the chunk address to this pointer. You can then `realloc` memory to incorporate this size change.

It will be something like:-

```
size_t sz = 10;
int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * sz); // sizeof(*arr)*sz (sizeof is operator)
if(!arr){
   perror("malloc");
   exit(1);
}
...
sz/=2; //correcting the size
int *p =realloc(arr,sizeof *arr * sz); 
if(!p){
   perror("realloc");
   exit(1);
}
arr = p;
...
free(arr);
```

Also macro is not a runtime thing - it is expanded at compile time. And more over you want the array to be resized in run time not compile time. Otherwise you can set the array size to be that size from the very beginning when you wrote the code. That's why *macro won't work here*.

Note that `arr` here is *not* an array - it is a pointer pointing to an allocated memory (the starting address of the memory chunk that was created using `malloc`). Nothing else.

Comment: @CookiePLMonster.: I editd both. Check it out

Comment: i think it should be free(p) instead of free(arr)

Comment: @AmarBal.:Nope...it is not a good way to do so. `arr = p` is there and it is done via `free(arr)`

Comment: btw, i understood the syntax, i was trying to use define, just checking if it could be used.

Comment: @AmarBal.: You know now it can't be used the way you did.... :)

Answer (score 0):

What you did was just changing a preprocessor constant. They are evaluated at compile time, so your redefinition is effectively pointless and takes no effect.

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, since this array is not going to be reallocated. If you **only** want to limit the amount of entries you are iterating through, ditch your `n` and replace it with something like:

```
static const size_t n = 10;
static size_t num_entries = n;
```

Then instead of redefining `n`, you should just do

```
num_entries = b;
```

and later on use this to iterate through the array. However, **do note that this does not reallocate the array so things are going to go terribly wrong if b is bigger than n**!

If you want to reallocate the array, you're better off reading up about `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`. As well as some fundamental tutorials about C in the meantime, since basing on your misunderstanding of what preprocessor (`#define`'d variables) are, you most likely just started with C.